# Using multiple processors with django-nose produces DatabaseError

Tags: django, postgresql, multiprocessing, factory-boy, django-nose

I am trying to run our test suite using `django-nose` with multiple processors to cutdown on runtime.  All tests pass with 1 processor, but using multiple processors produces a `DatabaseError: server closed the connection unexpectedly`

I found two tests that when run by themselves with multiple processors fail 90% of the time. A `UserFactory` is working with `accounts_user` and a `CustomerFactory` is working with `accounts_customer`.  Note in the **passing** log the final `UPDATE` to `accounts_customer` is completed before the transaction is closed.  In the **failing** log this `UPDATE` to `accounts_customer` never happens, since the transaction has already closed resulting in the `DatabaseError: server closed the connection unexpectedly`

I'm trying to decide what is causing the problem.  I think the problem is most likely with how django or postgres is handling transacations, but it could be any of the below.

- django 1.7
- python 2.7
- [django-nose](https://github.com/django-nose/django-nose)
- [factory_boy](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)
- postgres

**Passing** postgres log:

```
145 (PID: 44072, TID: 0, Host: ::1(58134)) LOG:  statement: SELECT * FROM "accounts_customer" INNER JOIN "accounts_user" ON ( "accounts_customer"."user_ptr_id" = "accounts_user"."id" ) WHERE "accounts_user"."email" = 'testJkQS.userUksx@example.com' LIMIT 21
146 (PID: 44072, TID: 0, Host: ::1(58134)) LOG:  duration: 1.927 ms
147 (PID: 44072, TID: 0, Host: ::1(58134)) LOG:  statement: SAVEPOINT "s140735112696576_x1"
148 (PID: 44072, TID: 0, Host: ::1(58134)) LOG:  duration: 0.041 ms
149 (PID: 44072, TID: 0, Host: ::1(58134)) LOG:  statement: SELECT (1) AS "a" FROM "accounts_customer" WHERE "accounts_customer"."account_number" = '87611264' LIMIT 1
150 (PID: 44072, TID: 0, Host: ::1(58134)) LOG:  duration: 0.187 ms
151 (PID: 44072, TID: 0, Host: ::1(58134)) LOG:  statement: INSERT INTO "accounts_user" ("password", "last_login", "email", "phone", "first_name", "last_name") VALUES ('', '2015-07-13 17:49:25.779534+00:00', 'testJkQS.userUksx@example.com', '', 'testJkQS', 'userUksx') RETURNING "accounts_user"."id"
152 (PID: 44072, TID: 394680, Host: ::1(58134)) LOG:  duration: 0.382 ms
153 (PID: 44072, TID: 394680, Host: ::1(58134)) LOG:  statement: INSERT INTO "accounts_customer" ("user_ptr_id", "advisor_id") VALUES (1, NULL)
154 (PID: 44072, TID: 394680, Host: ::1(58134)) LOG:  duration: 0.199 ms
155 (PID: 44072, TID: 394680, Host: ::1(58134)) LOG:  statement: RELEASE SAVEPOINT "s140735112696576_x1"
156 (PID: 44072, TID: 394680, Host: ::1(58134)) LOG:  duration: 0.022 ms
157 (PID: 44072, TID: 394680, Host: ::1(58134)) LOG:  statement: UPDATE "accounts_user" SET "password" = 'md5$LNepsrK4upi8$400710819735936b83344e0c47836251', "last_login" = '2015-07-13 17:49:25.779534+00:00', "is_superuser" = true, "email" = 'testJkQS.userUksx@example.com', "first_name" = 'testJkQS', "last_name" = 'userUksx' WHERE "accounts_user"."id" = 1
158 (PID: 44072, TID: 394680, Host: ::1(58134)) LOG:  duration: 0.363 ms
****159 (PID: 44072, TID: 394680, Host: ::1(58134)) LOG:  statement: UPDATE "accounts_customer" SET "advisor_id" = NULL WHERE "accounts_customer"."user_ptr_id" = 1
160 (PID: 44072, TID: 394680, Host: ::1(58134)) LOG:  duration: 0.274 ms
161 (PID: 44072, TID: 0, Host: ::1(58134)) LOG:  disconnection: session time: 0:00:00.156 user=rex database=test_db host=::1 port=58134
1 (PID: 44080, TID: 0, Host: ) LOG:  connection received: host=::1 port=58135
```

**Failing** postgres log:

```
143 (PID: 43828, TID: 0, Host: ::1(58068)) LOG:  statement: BEGIN
145 (PID: 43828, TID: 0, Host: ::1(58068)) LOG:  statement: SELECT * FROM "accounts_customer" INNER JOIN "accounts_user" ON ( "accounts_customer"."user_ptr_id" = "accounts_user"."id" ) WHERE "accounts_user"."email" = 'testhTiJ.userRxki@example.com' LIMIT 21
146 (PID: 43828, TID: 0, Host: ::1(58068)) LOG:  duration: 1.368 ms
147 (PID: 43828, TID: 0, Host: ::1(58068)) LOG:  statement: SAVEPOINT "s140735112696576_x1"
149 (PID: 43828, TID: 0, Host: ::1(58068)) LOG:  statement: SELECT (1) AS "a" FROM "accounts_customer" WHERE "accounts_customer"."account_number" = '71017283' LIMIT 1
150 (PID: 43828, TID: 0, Host: ::1(58068)) LOG:  duration: 0.198 ms
151 (PID: 43828, TID: 0, Host: ::1(58068)) LOG:  statement: INSERT INTO "accounts_user" ("password", "last_login", "email", "phone", "first_name", "last_name",) VALUES ('', '2015-07-13 17:48:01.528782+00:00', 'testhTiJ.userRxki@example.com', '', 'testhTiJ', 'userRxki', ) RETURNING "accounts_user"."id"
152 (PID: 43828, TID: 394672, Host: ::1(58068)) LOG:  duration: 0.351 ms
153 (PID: 43828, TID: 394672, Host: ::1(58068)) LOG:  statement: INSERT INTO "accounts_customer" ("user_ptr_id", "advisor_id") VALUES (1, NULL)
154 (PID: 43828, TID: 394672, Host: ::1(58068)) LOG:  duration: 0.176 ms
155 (PID: 43828, TID: 394672, Host: ::1(58068)) LOG:  statement: RELEASE SAVEPOINT "s140735112696576_x1"
156 (PID: 43828, TID: 394672, Host: ::1(58068)) LOG:  duration: 0.033 ms
157 (PID: 43828, TID: 394672, Host: ::1(58068)) LOG:  statement: UPDATE "accounts_user" SET "password" = 'md5$xN2n3doGJJHs$388f6cf97aa7ddba7c317108a7d4d511', "last_login" = '2015-07-13 17:48:01.528782+00:00', "email" = 'testhTiJ.userRxki@example.com', "first_name" = 'testhTiJ', "last_name" = 'userRxki' WHERE "accounts_user"."id" = 1
158 (PID: 43828, TID: 394672, Host: ::1(58068)) LOG:  duration: 0.291 ms
159 (PID: 43828, TID: 0, Host: ::1(58068)) LOG:  disconnection: session time: 0:00:00.142 user=rex database=test_db host=::1 port=58068
1 (PID: 43833, TID: 0, Host: ) LOG:  connection received: host=::1 port=58069
```

Stack-trace:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_my_test (website.apps.MyApp.tests.test_file.MyTestClass)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../tests/test_file.py", line 33, in test_my_test
    customer1 = accounts_factories.CustomerFactory()
  File "/Users/User/pkgs/MyProject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/factory/base.py", line 81, in __call__
    return cls.create(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/User/pkgs/MyProject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/factory/base.py", line 559, in create
    return cls._generate(True, attrs)
  File "/Users/User/pkgs/MyProject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/factory/base.py", line 492, in _generate
    cls._after_postgeneration(obj, create, results)
  File "/Users/User/pkgs/MyProject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/factory/django.py", line 156, in _after_postgeneration
    obj.save()
  File "/Users/User/pkgs/MyProject/MyProject/website/apps/accounts/models.py", line 198, in save
    return super(Customer, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/User/pkgs/MyProject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 589, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/Users/User/pkgs/MyProject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 617, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/Users/User/pkgs/MyProject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 679, in _save_table
    forced_update)
  File "/Users/User/pkgs/MyProject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 723, in _do_update
    return filtered._update(values) > 0
  File "/Users/User/pkgs/MyProject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 600, in _update
    return query.get_compiler(self.db).execute_sql(CURSOR)
  File "/Users/User/pkgs/MyProject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1005, in execute_sql
    cursor = super(SQLUpdateCompiler, self).execute_sql(result_type)
  File "/Users/User/pkgs/MyProject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 787, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/User/pkgs/MyProject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/User/pkgs/MyProject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/Users/User/pkgs/MyProject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
DatabaseError: server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.

-------------------- >> begin captured logging << --------------------
factory.generate: DEBUG: BaseFactory: Preparing accounts.factories.CustomerFactory(extra={})
factory.generate: DEBUG: <class 'accounts.factories.CustomerFactory'>: Setting up next sequence (0)
factory.containers: DEBUG: LazyStub: Computing values for accounts.factories.CustomerFactory(first_name=<OrderedDeclarationWrapper for <factory.fuzzy.FuzzyText object at 0x10bf1b350>>, last_name=<OrderedDeclarationWrapper for <factory.fuzzy.FuzzyText object at 0x10bf1b390>>, email=<OrderedDeclarationWrapper for <factory.declarations.LazyAttribute object at 0x10bf1b3d0>>)
factory.generate: DEBUG: LazyAttribute: Evaluating <function <lambda> at 0x10bf1d500> on <LazyStub for accounts.factories.CustomerFactory>
factory.containers: DEBUG: LazyStub: Computed values, got accounts.factories.CustomerFactory(first_name=u'testhTiJ', last_name=u'userRxki', email='testhTiJ.userRxki@example.com')
factory.generate: DEBUG: BaseFactory: Generating accounts.factories.CustomerFactory(first_name=u'testhTiJ', last_name=u'userRxki', email='testhTiJ.userRxki@example.com')
factory.generate: DEBUG: PostGenerationMethodCall: Calling <Customer: testhTiJ.userRxki@example.com>.set_password('secret')
--------------------- >> end captured logging << ---------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running django-nose on multiple processors doesn't work well with databases, or to be more exact, django transactions / database connectors.

Try using this package to split the tests: [nose-picker](https://github.com/eventbrite/nose-picker). Check the last section of this [tutorial](https://garciacode.wordpress.com/2015/07/14/optimizing-django-selenium-test-speed-test-faster/) on improving Django test performance.

Also, Python 3.4 includes an improved version of Sqlite3 which is supposed to be better at handling concurrency. YMMV.

Comment: Thanks David, much appreciated!  I've been playing around with nose-picker today and still getting a handle on how to best implement it, but it seems to be working.

Comment: Glad to hear. Could you upvote / accept my answer please? :)